# Resize jQuery .cycle() div

Tags: jquery, html, resize, height, cycle

I am in the process of trying to write a function that will scale the height of a div proportionally to the width of the div. I have been attempting to trigger an event on window.resize but with no luck so far. The width of the div currently resizes as desired but the height resizes outside of the bounds of the containing div elements start overlapping one another and are not wrapping properly. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
  jQuery:
  $(window).resize(function(){
       $('.bgCycle').each(function(){
            newHeight = $(this).parent('div').height();
            $(this).height(newHeight);
            $(this).children('div').height(newHeight);
       })
  })

  CSS:
 .bgCycle{
       border:1px solid red;
       position:relative;
       width:100% !important;
   }

  .imgContainerDiv{
       position:relative;
       width:100% !important;
   }

 HTML:
 <div class="bgCycle bgCycle1" style="z-index:1;">
     <div class="imgContainerDiv">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/aleo/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/img1.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
     </div>
     <div class="imgContainerDiv">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/aleo/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/img2.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="bgCycle bgCycle2" style="z-index:1;">
      <div class="imgContainerDiv">
           <img src="http://localhost:8888/aleo/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/img3.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="imgContainerDiv">
           <img src="http://localhost:8888/aleo/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/img4.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard without seeing your HTML, but I'm guessing that `$(this).parent('div').height();` should reference the window height possibly - `$(window).height();`?

```
newHeight = $(window).height();
```

Will that do what you want?

Comment: I've added the HTML output. I'm not sure if $(window).height(); would apply in this case. The problem is that .imgContainerDiv is getting larger but each containing div with class .bgCycle is only resizing the width. My logic is that if .bgCycle has the same height as .imgContainerDiv than they will both be assigned the same height and resize appropriately. I should also note that any content displayed below these divs is not wrapping down the page.

Comment: But the .bgCycle divs don't seem to have a parent div, so $(this).parent('div').height() wouldn't work? Perhaps if you made a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) it'd make more sense?